# i need to store the value in angularjs function

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-controller

im having **ng-change** function in the name of **myFunc()** to store the response from html **listitem**. 
the respose value is getting saved in the local variable of the function but when i refresh the controller or page the values are deleted. i need to store the value during **ng-change** in myFunc()  after multiple page or controller refersh the value will be stored in the controller variable to do the further logics
on **page onload**

```
myhtml code

<div class="col-sm-4">
    <ol name="ManualFiles" title="Select" required validType="select" ng-
     change="myFunc()" ng-model="data.manualsFiles" ng-selected="
     {{data.manualsFiles}}">
      <li nya-bs-option="type in manualsFiles" data-value="type.key">
      <a> {{type.val}} </a>
      </li>
     </ol>
  </div>
```

mycontroller code

```
    $scope.myFunc = function() {


         var manualFile=$scope.data.manualsFiles;
         var cdSoftwares=$scope.data.cdSoftware;
         var price=$scope.data.priceBook;
         var referenceBooks=$scope.data.referenceBook;
         var vpnAccounts=$scope.data.vpnAccount;




         if((manualFile && cdSoftwares && price &&  referenceBooks && vpnAccounts)!==0)
             {

             $scope.isTypeDisabled=false;
             }
         else
             {
             $scope.isTypeDisabled=true;
             $scope.data.status="Pending";


             }

        };
```

Comment: if you refresh the view, you'll lose your values. Try it using sessionStorage or Cache function from the browser.

Comment: To add to @KenrySanchez localStorage is another option.

Comment: try localStorage

Answer (score 0):

Try it using sessionStorage. In that way, you would not lose your values at least the user closes the window.

Now, the idea is, in the function `myFunc`,

```
$scope.myFunc = function() {

         var manualFile=$scope.data.manualsFiles;
         var cdSoftwares=$scope.data.cdSoftware;
         var price=$scope.data.priceBook;
         var referenceBooks=$scope.data.referenceBook;
         var vpnAccounts=$scope.data.vpnAccount;

         //Here, use sessionStorage to save your values in the browser.
         var data = {'manualFile': manualFile, 'cdSoftwares': cdSoftwares, 'price': price, 'referenceBooks': referenceBooks, 'vpnAccounts': vpnAccounts}

         sessionStorage.setItem('yourNameKey', data);

         if((manualFile && cdSoftwares && price &&  referenceBooks && vpnAccounts)!==0)
             {

             $scope.isTypeDisabled=false;
             }
         else
             {
             $scope.isTypeDisabled=true;
             $scope.data.status="Pending";


             }

        };
```

Then, when Users are refreshing the site, you would create a function just for recover that values in your variables. You'd use `destructuring assignment` to recover your values.

```
function recoverValues() {
  var data = sessionStorage.getItem('yourNameKey');
  var { manualFile, cdSoftwares, price, referenceBooks, vpnAccounts } = data;
}

recoverValues();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **sessionStorage** property of **$window**.

Note: The data stored using **sessionStorage** will be available only in that session. (data will get deleted when the browser tab is closed)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your requirement using this example. [Try this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gioeleslfierro/s0pm6gcq/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var app = angular.module('MyApp', ["ngStorage"])
        app.controller('MyController', function ($scope, $localStorage, $sessionStorage, $window) {
            $scope.Save = function () {
                $localStorage.LocalMessage = "LocalStorage: My name is Pet Jones.";
                $sessionStorage.SessionMessage = "SessionStorage: My name isPet Jones.";
                                    OR
               $sessionStorage.setItem("status", "pending");
            }
            $scope.Get = function () {
                $window.alert($localStorage.LocalMessage + "\n" + $sessionStorage.SessionMessage);
                                    OR
                console.log($sessionStorage.getItem("status"))
            }
        });
</script>
```